# Merge two data frames by matching levels of factor- matching factor levels added as columns

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two df. They differ in the number of rows but have a common column `lepsp`.

```
set.seed(571) 
year = as.factor(c(rep("1998", 20), rep("1999", 16)))
lepsp = c(letters[1:20], c('a','b','c'),letters[8:20]) 
freq = rpois(36, lambda=12)
df1 <- data.frame(year, lepsp, freq)

lepsp = c(letters[1:26],c('a','b','c'),letters[1:20],c('e','f',"h")) 
plntsp = c(paste("plnt", sep= "_", letters[1:26]), 
      paste("plnt",sep="_",letters[1:20]),
      paste("plnt",sep="_",letters[18:23])) 
df2 <- data.frame(lepsp, plntsp)
```

I would like to match `lepsp` in both data frames and add a column(s) to `df1` that specify each `plntsp`  associated with each  `lepsp`. Each unique `plntsp` needs to be merged as a new column(s). If there is no associated plant, then those entries can be left blank. The new df should look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(lepsp=unique(c(letters[1:5],letters[14:18])),  
          plntsp1=c("","","plnt_a","plnt_b","plnt_c","","","","",""),
          plntsp2=c("","","", "plnt_c","plnt_d","","","","",""))
```

I have used this in the past for matching, but am not sure how to adjust it so that each level of `plntsp` is added as a new column.

```
 df1$plntsp<-df2$plntsp[match(df1$lepsp, df2$lepsp)]
```

Comment: `letters[seq(from = 1, to = 20 )]` can simply be written `letters[1:20]`. And `letters[1:26]` is simply `letters`

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, on='plntsp', ...)`, but I'm not clear on how the merged result df you give relates to df1 and df2.

Answer (score 0):

You can join `df1` and `df2` using `dplyr::left_join`. Summarize data for `leapsp`. Finally, use `splitstackshape::cSplit` separate `plntsp` in multiple columns as:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)

left_join(df1, df2, by="lepsp") %>%
  select(lepsp, plntsp) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(lepsp) %>%
  summarise(plntsp = toString(plntsp)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  cSplit("plntsp")

#    lepsp plntsp_1 plntsp_2 plntsp_3
# 1:     a   plnt_a   plnt_d       NA
# 2:     b   plnt_b   plnt_e       NA
# 3:     c   plnt_c   plnt_f       NA
# 4:     d   plnt_d   plnt_g       NA
# 5:     e   plnt_e   plnt_h   plnt_u
# 6:     f   plnt_f   plnt_i   plnt_v
# 7:     g   plnt_g   plnt_j       NA
# 8:     h   plnt_h   plnt_k   plnt_w
# 9:     i   plnt_i   plnt_l       NA
# 10:     j   plnt_j   plnt_m       NA
# 11:     k   plnt_k   plnt_n       NA
# 12:     l   plnt_l   plnt_o       NA
# 13:     m   plnt_m   plnt_p       NA
# 14:     n   plnt_n   plnt_q       NA
# 15:     o   plnt_o   plnt_r       NA
# 16:     p   plnt_p   plnt_s       NA
# 17:     q   plnt_q   plnt_t       NA
# 18:     r   plnt_r       NA       NA
# 19:     s   plnt_s       NA       NA
# 20:     t   plnt_t       NA       NA
```

**Note:** Please use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument while creating data frame to avoid unnecessary warnings.